# backend of Codeigniter 2.2 project with several templates

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

In Codeigniter 2.2 project I want to make several templates for backend and in db table of user save which template is used for user.
When User opens login page then default template is opened, as user is not logged yet.
On login I save in session current template name.
But problem is that in my config file I have several blocks for pagination layout.
Different templates use diffrent tags for pagination layout.
So in config file I have to write something like:

```
if ( $current_template == 'template_name' ) {
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<p>';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</p>';
}...
```

But it looks like that CI get_instance() method is not accessible in config file!
Which can be decision for this ? If are there some good tools for this?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your server side code is consistent, view is consistent just changes in css/js otherwise for different views, same methodology can be extended.

If you are making template based UI then you should have modular approach for displaying the contents e.g for view page you must have header, footer & main content part. Now if you have different templates then you should have css/js files in with same names in different template directories as shown in picture below:
[image: Codeigniter Templating System]

After the user login save the template name in session and your theme will be dynamic as below code will be used to load css/js

```
<?php
$templateName=$this->session->userdata('currentTemplate');
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url().'ui_components'.$templateName>?>/css/style.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'ui_components/'.$templateName?>/js/main.js"></script>
```

You can try this type of simple templating system.