# How to setup HMVC and multiple theme structure with codeigniter?

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have setup HMVC with codeigniter but I am confused how to create setup for themes.

I am planning like
/themes/themename/modulename/template
/themes/themename/modulename/view

If any view file is not found in themes folder it should load from
modules/modulename/view/

these template and view should be managed by administrator(database).
How to achieve this?

Comment: For templating part visit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469662/backend-of-codeigniter-2-2-project-with-several-templates/25474864#25474864 and for HMVC use this useful link of implementation http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/hmvc-an-introduction-and-application--net-11850

Comment: This is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Please post more information in detail

Comment: I downloaded codeingnitor , and setup for HMVC, created modules. all is working. Now I want to setup for themes as specified in question.

Comment: @user3702906 have you found solution/answer for your requirement/question setup hmvc and multiple theme structure with codeigniter ?